# Why can't I perform 'certain' actions in export class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, components

I have this question when I try to implent logic in export classes. I can declare variables but they behave static and final.When I try to change them with normal typescript logic, I get errors. Why is this? see the example here below:

- land = counrty
- landen = countries

but that is irrelevant I guess.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Land } from './model/land';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  //templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  template:`<h1>{{title}}</h1>
              <h2>Details van {{land.name}}</h2>
              <div><label>id: </label>{{land.id}}</div>
              <div>
                <label>naam: </label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="land.name" placeholder="name">
              </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  //this goes perfect
  landen: Land[] = [
    {id: 1, name:"Belgium"},
    {id: 2, name: "Holland"}
  ];

//if declare array like below and then insert values, it doesn't work
  landen: Land[] = [];
  landen[0] = {id: 1, name:"Belgium"};
  landen[1] = {id: 2, name:"Holland"};

}
```

module since requested

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   FormsModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the question should be tagged a "Java" question? I don't see Java relevance here, JavaScript, yes, but not Java.

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: You can't run code inside a class definition, you will want to put your assignment code into the `constructor`.   `behave static and final` indeed, that's another issue with it, you have a global instance of  `{id: 1, name:"Belgium"},` that your adding to this list, change any one instance of this list, and all will change.

Comment: @Keith, How would this work with an array? Since I use the constructor in export classes?

Comment: @YannickMussche  Deans answer shows you,  but just ignore the bit about `static and final`, as I've just tested it in Playground, and you get different instances.  So I'm not sure what you mean by `static` and `final`... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can't run code inside a class definition, you will want to put your assignment code into the constructor.  `behave static and final` indeed, that's another issue with it, you have a global instance of  `{id: 1, name:"Belgium"},` that your adding to this list, change any one instance of this list, and all will change. - Keith

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Land } from './model/land';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  //templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  template:`<h1>{{title}}</h1>
              <h2>Details van {{land.name}}</h2>
              <div><label>id: </label>{{land.id}}</div>
              <div>
                <label>naam: </label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="land.name" placeholder="name">
              </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  //this goes perfect
  landen: Land[] = [
    {id: 1, name:"Belgium"},
    {id: 2, name: "Holland"}
  ];

  constructor(){
    landen[0] = {id: 1, name:"Belgium"};
    landen[1] = {id: 2, name:"Holland"};
  }
}
```

Comment: I also get an error using that code. It seems very hard to understand that I can take information from a database and only display it? Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to say?

Comment: @YannickMussche i fixed the code, you can redefine the type

Comment: This works, but you should also let landen = []; out the constructor, than the array doesn't get overwritten with an empty array first! I will mark it as correct answer but best to change it. I tested it with multiple values and only 1 to overwrite

Comment: @YannickMussche done that, yeah, no prob, thanks bro